# Swift 2.0: Creating a Collection Type of Objects that conform to a Generic Protocol

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols

For example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias T
    func doSomething(something: T)
}
let a = Array<SomeProtocol>()
```

I want to have an Array which is an array of objects that conform to `SomeProtocol`.  Which seems fine in theory but I get the following error message:

> Cannot be used as a generic constraint because it contains assosciated
>   type requirements.

And I guess that makes sense, after all an Array is a generic struct also so the compiler won't be able to figure out what the type actually is given that both `SomeProtocol` and `Array` are generic.

So my question is - I feel like I should be able have an array of objects that conform to `SomeProtocol` - is this possible currently in Swift 2.0?  Am I thinking about this in all the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error message is the following problem which occurs if your `Array` declaration would work:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias T
    func doSomething(something: T)
}
// has already some values
let a: Array<SomeProtocol> = [...]

// what type should be passed as parameter?
// the type of T in SomeProtocol is not defined
a[0].doSomething(...)
```

As workaround you can make a generic wrapper struct for any type of `SomeProtocol` so you can specify the type of `T` (like in the Swift standard library AnyGenerator, AnySequence,...).

```
struct AnySomeProtocol<T>: SomeProtocol {
    let _doSomething: T -> ()
    // can only be initialized with a value of type SomeProtocol
    init<Base: SomeProtocol where Base.T == T>(_ base: Base) {
        _doSomething = base.doSomething
    }
    func doSomething(something: T) {
        _doSomething(something)
    }
}
```

now you use an array of type `[AnySomeProtocol<T>]` (replace `T` with any type you want) and before appending an element convert it to `AnySomeProtocol`:

```
var array = [AnySomeProtocol<String>]()
array.append(AnySomeProtocol(someType))

// doSomething can only be called with a string 
array[0].doSomething("a string")
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible as now in Swift 2. A generic type cannot be used until its generic parameter has been specified. In the case of generic classes, structs and enums, their generic parameters can be specified at the same time when they are used. For instance an Array can be used like this:

```
let anArray: [String]
```

Here the generic parameter of `Array` is specified to `String` when the `Array` is used as the type of a variable.

However, a generic protocol (protocol that has associated types, named typealias) can only have its associated types be specified when a concrete type conforms to it. There is no way you can supply the associated types when you use a generic protocol as the type of a variable like generic classes, structs or enums do.